# How to do aggressive inlining with JS compiler/parser/transformer?

Tags: javascript, parsing, inlining

I'm trying to figure out how to do aggressive inlining of JS code. Here is an example:

```js
// Source code
var fruits = {
  'a': { name: 'apple' },
  'b': { name: 'banana' }
};


function getFruit(n) {
  return fruits[n];
}

console.log(getFruit('a'));
console.log(getFruit('b'));
```

If I use **Google Closure Compiler** on this code with `optimization` set to `advanced`, I get the following:

```js
// Closure output
var a = {a:{name:"apple"}, b:{name:"banana"}};
console.log(a.a);
console.log(a.b);
```

This is great as the function `getFruit` is inlined but the object `a` is still there and I want this:

```js
console.log({a:{name:"apple"}, b:{name:"banana"}}.a);
console.log({a:{name:"apple"}, b:{name:"banana"}}.b);
```

Of course the purpose of Closure is to minify as well so if the object `a` is used more than once, it doesn't get inlined. If I remove the `console.log(getFruit('b'));` then I get what I want.

**Prepack** doesn't help much either:

```js
// Prepack output
var getFruit, fruits;
(function () {
  var _$0 = this;

  var _9 = function (n) {
    return fruits[n];
  };

  _$0.getFruit = _9;
  var _2 = {
    name: "apple"
  };
  var _4 = {
    name: "banana"
  };
  _$0.fruits = {
    a: _2,
    b: _4
  };
  console.log(_2);
  console.log(_4);
}).call(this);
```

So my question is, is there any way I can use a compiler/parser with an ad-hoc rule that can aggressively inline any expression whose evaluation result can be known at compile time? In other word, it should remove all the indirections as much as possible.

**WHY**:

Because I wanna know if the `console.log` function is called with a specific argument value at `compile` time. By compile time I mean by just looking at the code statically without having to run it cause I have that information already. The `fruits` object doesn't change after I run this code.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198270/discussion-on-question-by-norbertpy-how-to-do-aggressive-inlining-with-js-compil).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the task is too narrow to find a ready-to-use tool. As you can see, Google Closure Compiler optimizes code size (well, it could optimize this particular example better, like to

```
console.log({name:"apple"});
console.log({name:"banana"});
```

which you can perhaps discuss with authors) and not the number of variables (quite an uncommon metric). Also, object initialization can even change script's behavior (`{a:1} != {a:1}`, right? while with `var o = {a:1}` this is true: `o == o`), which makes the desirable result even more exotic.

However, you can create such tool by actually analysing the JS syntax and manipulating structures which describe it. Such structures are called [abstract syntax trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) and probably the most well-known tool(*) to manipulate those (creating so called **codemods**) is https://github.com/facebook/jscodeshift .

Note: creating codemods is not an easy ride, so I think to create one of those you should either have a *very* good reason or be interested to learn and do some complicated stuff for fun. There's not much documentation or articles on the topic either, but perhaps enough already. [This](https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-parsing-abstract-syntax-trees-asts-5-tips-on-how-to-minimize-parse-time-abfcf7e8a0c8) may be helpful as an introduction to ASTs and [this](https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/turbocharged-javascript-refactoring-with-codemods-b0cae8b326b9) contains a number of nice codemod examples as well as links to "how to write your own codemod" things.

(*) I mean manipulation customized by you; the most well-known tool in JS world that is based on ASTs is probably Babel (or may be TypeScript or some other thing that parses/produces JS)

Comment: Thanks. I already use `ast` to query for a particular set of expressions but it was hard to keep track of the lexical scope variables and replace them in-place. I think I can read the ast top-down and collect and carry all the `values` at each step so I can do my thing.

Comment: @norbertpy hm, sounds like you can improve your question to get more relevant answers: first, if you share the code you tried to manipulate AST and describe how it fails to meet your needs and ask a more specific question, nobody will tell that it's off-topic; second, you can try more relevant tags like [abstract-syntax-tree] which may also bring better answers. I'm not an expert with codemods, I'm just aware of those, but there are definitely some guys who can help in a more precise way. (if you unaccept the answer to get more attention, I won't mind)

Comment: @norbertpy and another pointer: if you try to answer the "why" thing more thoroughly, that will also help to grab more attention, because solving a puzzle that starts with a good story is usually rewarding by itself

Comment: Thanks, I think I can figure it out from here. Already exhausted replying to nitpicks up there.